# Is there any intuitive explanation why I can calculate $E(X+Y)$?

Tags: probability, intuition

I am reading a book about probability and statistics for high-school students (in Japanese).

> I have $13$ cards.
> Each of the $13$ cards has $5$ or $10$ on its front side.
> Each of the $13$ cards has $2$ or $3$ on its back side.
> The number of cards which have $5$ on its front sides is $6$.
> The number of cards which have $10$ on its front sides is $7$.
> The number of cards which have $2$ on its back sides is $9$.
> The number of cards which have $3$ on its back sides is $4$.
> When I draw a card from the $13$ cards, let $X$ be the number on its front side.
> When I draw a card from the $13$ cards, let $Y$ be the number on its back side.
> Calculate $E(X+Y)$.

My answer is here:

> $E(X) = 5\times\frac{6}{13}+10\times\frac{7}{13}$.
> $E(Y) = 2\times\frac{9}{13}+3\times\frac{4}{13}$.
> So, $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)=5\times\frac{6}{13}+10\times\frac{7}{13}+2\times\frac{9}{13}+3\times\frac{4}{13}$.

I don't know the number of cards which have $5$ on its front sides and $2$ on its back sides.
I don't know the number of cards which have $5$ on its front sides and $3$ on its back sides.
I don't know the number of cards which have $10$ on its front sides and $2$ on its back sides.
I don't know the number of cards which have $10$ on its front sides and $3$ on its back sides.
But I get $E(X+Y)$.
I feel strange.

Is there any intuitive explanation why I can calculate $E(X+Y)$?

Comment: Can you give an intuitive explanation of why yhou think the four things you don't know are felevant to $E(X+Y)$?

Comment: You also don’t know that $X$ and $Y$ happen in the same draw. (But if it did, it wouldn’t matter.)

Comment: If you have a business selling cigarettes and lottery tickets, and you know that your average daily revenue from cigarettes is \$50 and your average daily revenue from lottery tickets is \$35, is that enough information to compute your average total daily revenue? Do you need to know how many customers buy cigarettes without buying a lottery ticket and how many buy a lottery ticket without buying cigarettes?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @bof Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: See the [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) article, which contains a proof of the relevant assertion.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: do you need to know the grade of each individual student in a course to know what is the course average grade? Expectation is that, essentially, an average. Sum of outcomes divided by the number of events, i.e. sum of grades divided by number of students.

Comment: Steve, Thank you very much for your answer.